# When I try to send a location update to the emulator I get an error message

Tags: android, controls, location, emulation, ddms

When I am in the emulator control view in the DDMS I am attempting to send a Mock Location to my emulator. However when I try this I get the following error message, "Unable to send command to the emulator". I cannot understand why this is not working as it was fine yesterday and I havent made any changes to my application. Please help?

Comment: First Run your app on that emulator and then update the location in your DDMS.Then after appying the changes,just check it(include in your code,a toast which works when the location changes).Am sure,it will work fine and give you a toast

Comment: I've just close Emulator Control window and re-open again.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same problem. After restarting process of adb.exe from task manager it worked.

Comment: I also had to restart eclipse. But this helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you use mobile device for checking results, I think in your code, you would have mentioned the NETWORK_PROVIDER in location manager. If it is, then change it to GPS_PROVIDER and dont forget to add the permissions in your manifest file(android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION). And now send the command through emulator control. it will work.